# XmlDocument in WinRT functionally identical to System.XML.XmlDocument?

Tags: xml, windows-runtime

I am trying to figure out the purpose of Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument in comparison to the (.NET) class in System.XML and XElement/XDocument. Until the resurrection of XmlDocument in WinRT I thought that XmlDocument was, well, "old style" (W3C DOM). XElement did all the work for me, was faster and allowed LINQ.

Now XmlDocument is back and all I've seen so far seems basically identical to the old XmlDocument. I am looking for reasons to use this class rather than XElement (apart from the fact that XmlDocument works with StorageFile). I would appreciate to get some ideas, facts or experiences.

Answer (score 0):

`XmlDocument` is a document, however `XmlElement` represents an element in the document. I think that the difference is quite clear.

Comment: You certainly misread the question :-) I did not ask about the difference between XmlDocument and XmlElement. I asked why the Windows Runtime implements the W3C DOM after the new X DOM (or whatever you may call it) in form of XDocument, XElement etc. was introduced only a few years ago as the better replacement for the W3C DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a right answer. My take on it is that XmlDocument and friends were ported for those people that like it, and those teams where this type is known already.

I sometimes use XmlDocument to read when I'm in an XPath kind of mood, although I use XDocument to write, since I just find the XmlDocument API hard work for building XML.

Luke